# How do you supress OpenGL messages in Xcode for iOS 12.0

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using an old version of Cocos2d-iphone and need to come up with one last release before I completely reconfigure my app for Metal support.  Until then, I'm trying to work through all the deprecated issues besides the OpenGL stuff.  As it is, I have well over 400+ messages that say

```
"_____ is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 - OpenGLES API deprecated. (Define GLES_SILENCE_DEPRECATION to silence these warnings)_
```

Where do I define this in my project?  I tried putting it in the top of my global.h header as well as a few other places, but I can't seem to get rid of it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Define it under Preprocessor Macros in Build Settings:

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: The warnings remain.
'EAGLContext' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 - OpenGLES API deprecated. (Define GLES_SILENCE_DEPRECATION to silence these warnings)

Comment: You sure you're defining it under the right project level? I checked the SDK, it's still in there.

Comment: Oh no, it was in the wrong bit!  I had put it in the 'Preprocessor Macros Not Used In Precompiled Headers' where something else was - it's and old project.  Now I've got a findable/resolvable 28 warnings instead of 572.  Phew.  Thanks so much.

Comment: ftr you don't have to set `GLES_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1`, simply adding `GLES_SILENCE_DEPRECATION` to the list works